# tailwind dark mode does not working with the prefix, why?

Tags: tailwind-css, prefix, darkmode

before I use the prefix , I could use dark mode normally , but after made a prefix to my tailwind classes , I cannot use the dark mode no longer , anyone know how to toggle dark mode with prefix ?, please

Comment: Please include your `tailwind.config.js` and a code example of how you are applying the prefix. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments , I have found how to fix the problem

Answer (score 6):

Your prefix needs be there in the dark mode class as well.
the below example assumes you have `tw` as configured prefix

```
<!-- add your prefix here too -->
<html class="tw-dark">
<body>
  <!-- apply dark mode class with prefix -->
  <div class="bg-white dark:tw-bg-black">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you don't want the prefix for the `dark` class then tweak the config:-

```
/** tailwind.config.js */
prefix: 'tw-',
darkMode: ['class', '[class="dark"]',
...
```

this will allow you to switch to dark mode without adding the prefix

```
<!-- now no need to prefix tw-dark -->
<html class="dark">
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. very helpfull. don´t find it in the docs.

Comment: Why is this not documented? I had the exact same issue when applying a prefix for my UI lib. Dark mode never worked inside my UI package but now after changing 'darkMode' property to what you have suggested - it actually worked! Thank you.

Comment: It's not working with Nuxt 3. I've tried all the ways. Used `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` and the direct implementation. Also closed ssr in the nuxt config file. Without prefix, it works :\

Comment: It is working. However, if you have another classes in html, this is the correct way: `darkMode: ['class', '[class*="dark"]'],`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was @servetoz [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71461174/tailwind-dark-mode-does-not-working-with-the-prefix-why#comment137665382_73509187). You should set `darkMode: ['class', '[class*="dark"]']` in tailwind.config.js